# Hibernate and Oracle order by given order

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate

I am using a similar query like the one posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689914/what-is-the-best-way-of-selecting-a-set-of-objects-by-given-ids-in-given-order-w) to obtain an object list in a given order.

I also have two environments, one of them uses MySQL and the other one uses Oracle. In MySQL, the HQL given in that answer (posted here for refernece) works fine, but when switching to Oracle it translates to the same resulting SQL which is not valid.

```
select q from Question q where q.id in (:ids) ORDER BY FIELD(id, :ids)
```

So I wanted to extend Oracle10gDialect and provide the translation into this Oracle compliant SQL:

```
 select q.id            
        from
            Question q
        where
            q.id in (
                1701, 1698, 1264
            ) 
        order by
            decode(q.id,
            1701, 1, 1698, 2, 1264 , 3 )
```

But I don't know how to define my function. When dealing with bitwise and I extended the Dialect and used this code:

```
registerFunction("bwand", new SQLFunctionTemplate(IntegerType.INSTANCE, "BITAND(?1, ?2)"));
```

which works fine, but in this case the pattern I need to provide is the id list, followed by its order index, and I don't know how to get that index number.

Any help?

Comment: If the number of objects is small you can do the sort in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle, MySQL, and (I believe) Hibernate all support the `case` statement in the `order by` clause.

So you can write this as:

```
order by (case when q.id = 1701 then 1
               when q.id = 1698 then 2
               when q.id = 12c4 then 3
          end)
```