# Grails withCriteria fetch, or a fast way to sort in predetermined order

Tags: hibernate, grails, criteria, hibernate-criteria

A database function returns id's of all events within a certain radius, ordered by their distance.

Afterwards, to preserve performance I'm eagerly loading necessary collections in `withCriteria` like this:

```
    def events = Event.withCriteria {
        'in'('id', ids)
        fetchMode("someRelation", FetchMode.JOIN)
        // a few more joins
        setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
    }
```

However this messes up the ordering. I've noticed that the result of this criteria query returns all events sorted by id. Which does somewhat make sense since `in` doesn't guarantee any sort of special ordering (nor does it make any sense that it should). However this poses a bit of a problem, since I want this list to be ordered.

So what I did was this:

```
    List<Event> temp = [];
    ids.each { id -> temp << events.find { it.id == id } }
    events = temp;
```

However when the list contains ~2400 elements this piece of code adds around 1 second to total execution time which is something I wish to lower as much as possible.

Is there any other way of doing this which could speed up the process?

Comment: Have you tried adding `order("id", "asc")` to your criteria?

Comment: @lifeisfoo That would order my events by their id in ascending order. However that is not what I want. I have a predetermined order or event id's by distance (which i receive from my database function, and distance is not a property but a calculated value). I wish to somehow keep that order, or quickly sort according to it in/after the criteria in my thread post.

Comment: Look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689914/what-is-the-best-way-of-selecting-a-set-of-objects-by-given-ids-in-given-order-w . You could try this technique using Grails HQL interface https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#hql

Comment: @lifeisfoo thanks for the help, that's what I'm looking for, however since I'm using postgres as my RDBMS I don't have the luxury of `order by field` and since I'm also using `distinct` due to eager fetch joins I can't seem to use the alternative solutions for field ordering. I guess I'll have to come up with something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that there are at least three way to solve your problem (I've done additional researches and considerations):

### SQL way

According to [this gist](https://gist.github.com/cpjolicoeur/3590737), *ordering by field* is possibile also with Postgres and not only in mysql, but it's a little bit tricky since it's not directly supported. As you can read in the gist discussion there are different approaches, but I think that the cleaner and simpler is the last: adding a custom *order by* clause!

```
ORDER BY (ID=10, ID=2, ID=56, ID=40) DESC
```

To create a custom SQL query in Grails that returns objects with a specific type, you can follow [this tutorial](http://mrhaki.blogspot.it/2014/03/grails-goodness-using-hibernate-native.html)

### Groovy way (your current)

```
// only four id, for the sake of simplicity
def ids = [10, 2, 56, 40];

// get your events with your criteria
def events = Event.withCriteria {
    'in'('id', ids)
    fetchMode("someRelation", FetchMode.JOIN)
    // a few more joins
    setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
}

// create an array that maps event.id -> sortedEventIndex
def indexToIdArray = [];
// event with id 2 is at index 1
// event with id 10 is at index 0 
// ...
// [null, null, 1 , null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 0, ...]
ids.eachWithIndex{ num, idx -> indexToIdArray[$num] = $idx }

def sortedEvents = [];
events.each { ev -> sortedEvents[indexToIdArray[ev.id]] = ev }
```

In this way you have sorted in *O*(n), consuming some additional memory.
I don't know if this solution really performs better than your but you should give it a try.

See also [this interesting article](http://groovyalgorithms.altervista.org/groovy-profiling-with-gprof/) on how to find performance issue in your groovy code.

### Client way

Return the unsorted list of events to the client with sorting data, then sort them in the client. If a client of your application can sort the events list in more ways, I think that this solution could be useful (every sorting action is done only client side).

### the 4th, the 5th, ...

Since this is a also a performance problem, there are other possible solutions (depends on your domain/environment):

- Cache eagerly everything, even the ordered result
- Use a fixed list of points for sorting (if I'm near p1, use p1 for sorting)
- Your ideas

I hope this helps.