# SpringData - MongoDB fetch objects by IDs in the given order

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

I have a usecase like this. I have questions in my Mongo DB and have a CRUD micro service. There I have exposed an API method to fetch questions by list of IDs given via query params. Let say for the simplicity sake, user gives `/api/questions?id=2, id=7, id=4, id = 5`

then I need to return list of questions in that exact same order, like so

```
questions: [
    {
       id: 2,
       prompt: "prompt one",
       ...
    },
    {
        id: 7,
        prompt: "prompt two",
        ...
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        ...
    },
    {
        id: 5
        ...
    }
]
```

But notice that this is neither ASC nor DESC, rather can be any arbitrary order like `/api/questions?id=2, id=7, id=4, id=5`

I am using `org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository` as my `DAO` class. Currently I am doing ordering inside my service layer after fetching the data through the repository which is based on spring-data. That solution works. But I would rather prefer to get this ordering done at the DAO repository level itself, since it costs less and does not add unnecessary complexity to my business logic at the service layer. Rather I can delegate the responsibility merely to the DB, assuming it is more capable of doing such things with more optimizations.

The Mongo document structure looks like this.
[image]

Can I achieve this using spring data?
If so how to get that thing done?

Comment: Is `questions` an array field of your structure? If yes, then it is possible but you'd have to use aggregation, because sorting arrays is a bit trickier than sorting any other field that is not an array. If you can provide a dummy example of your data structure I can help you with it. Also what query are you using right know to fetch the documents?

Comment: I am using default `this.questionRepository.findAll(ids);` now. I am searching for a condensed way. I believe aggregation would be more verbose way. Isn't that so? I don't have `mongoTemplate` with me in that repository.

Comment: It is more verbose, but there is no way around it, if you want to sort an array. It would still be faster then sorting in your code. But if your `ids` are not inside an array you can use `this.questionRepository.findAll(ids).sort({id: -1});` or `sort({id: 1});`. As I said if you update your question with a dummy document then I can tell you whether you need only sort or rather aggregation.

Comment: I have added the document structure as per your request. If there's a condensed way of doing this please do let me know. Thanks !

Comment: Well you pasted an image. A dummy json would have been great. But anyway, now it's at least clear that you have to use aggregation and you'd have to `$unwind` your array in order to be able to order it. You mentioned you search like that `this.questionRepository.findAll(ids)` what is `ids`? Cause I can't imaging that `"options.id": { $in: [2, 7, 4, 5]}`  would return documents that only contain arrays that have `id:2, id:7, id:4 and id:5`. It would also return arrays that have  `id:2, id:8, id:4 and id:5`

Comment: Id denotes the question ID value. 2, 7, etc were just a few dummy values. Actual ID is a mongo generated literal like a UUID and you may see it in the above image.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using `MongoRepository` then create an interface that extends it. Example:

```
public interface MyRepository extends MongoRepository<Question, String>{

    @Query("{_id: { $in: ?0 } })")
    List<Question> findByIds(List<String> ids, Sort sort);
}
```

Then in your Service class or wherever you use your repository. Add the following:

```
Sort sort = new Sort(Direction.ASC,"_id"); // Or DESC
List<Question> questionsById = repository.findByIds(ids, sort);
```

Of course Question here is a dummy class that I created to test it out, replace it with yours.

---

Ok if you need by input user order then you really can't come around using aggregation framework.

If I have the following dataset in my databse inserted in that order:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a103a434d8a2fe38bec5c5e"),
    "prompt" : "prompt one"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a103a434d8a2fe38bec5c60"),
    "prompt" : "prompt two"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a103a434d8a2fe38bec5c62"),
    "prompt" : "prompt three"
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a103a434d8a2fe38bec5c64"),
    "prompt" : "prompt four"
}
```

Then the aggregation pipeline would have to look like:

```
db.getCollection('questions').aggregate([{
        "$match": {
            "_id": {
                "$in": [ObjectId("5a103a434d8a2fe38bec5c62"), ObjectId("5a103a434d8a2fe38bec5c60"), ObjectId("5a103a434d8a2fe38bec5c64"), ObjectId("5a103a434d8a2fe38bec5c5e")]
            },
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "orderByInputId": {
                "$cond": [{
                        "$eq": ["$_id", ObjectId("5a103a434d8a2fe38bec5c62")]
                    },
                    1,
                    {
                        "$cond": [{
                                "$eq": ["$_id", ObjectId("5a103a434d8a2fe38bec5c60")]
                            },
                            2,
                            {
                                "$cond": [{
                                        "$eq": ["$_id", ObjectId("5a103a434d8a2fe38bec5c64")]
                                    },
                                    3,
                                    4
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            prompt: 1
        }
    },

    // Sort the results
    {
        "$sort": {
            "orderByInputId": 1
        }
    }
])
```

and the results I get are the following:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a103a434d8a2fe38bec5c62"),
    "prompt" : "prompt three",
    "orderByInputId" : 1.0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a103a434d8a2fe38bec5c60"),
    "prompt" : "prompt two",
    "orderByInputId" : 2.0
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a103a434d8a2fe38bec5c64"),
    "prompt" : "prompt four",
    "orderByInputId" : 3.0
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a103a434d8a2fe38bec5c5e"),
    "prompt" : "prompt one",
    "orderByInputId" : 4.0
}
```

Comment: First part is correct, but the second part is not. I want to order the questions based on the order in which ID is provided. Say if user gives question ID values as 2, 4, 7 then I need to order questions in the same order of input ID values. So neither `ASC` nor `DESC` works here. Thanks !

Comment: A similar usecase using RDBMS can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689914/what-is-the-best-way-of-selecting-a-set-of-objects-by-given-ids-in-given-order-w

Comment: @RavindraRanwala I updated the answer. As mentioned if you want your custom order (user input order) then you can't come around aggregation framework.

Comment: Yeah thanks ! Aggregation solution seems more verbose, complex and less readable and not maintainable. Doing the ordering in the service layer takes just 3 lines of code. I would keep it. Thanks a lot !